# Trying to read a file in python

Tags: python

Please can anyone help me reading .txt file in python

here is my code

```
flink open(2of12inf.txt, "rU")
```

But I am getting an error

Comment: *what* error do you get?

Comment: http://nixcraft.com/coding-general/13455-how-python-read-text-file.html

Comment: have you tried `with open("yourfilename.txt","r") as my_open_file:`?

Answer (score 3):

You forgot an `=` assignment statement and quotes:

```
flink = open('2of12inf.txt', "rU")
```

It's best practice to open a file as a context manager (the [`with` statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with)) so that it is closed automatically:

```
with open('2of12inf.txt', "rU") as flink:
    # do something with the open file object

# flink will be closed automatically.
```

`flink` is a [file object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects), so you can use methods like `.read()`, `.readline()`, etc. to read from it. Or you can loop over the object (iterate) to get single lines each time:

```
with open('2of12inf.txt', "rU") as flink:
    for line in flink:
        # do something with each line.
```

I'd use a absolute path to the file instead of a relative path to avoid surprises:

```
with open('/path/to/directory/with/2of12inf.txt', "rU") as flink:
```

or you can use the [`os.path` library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) to construct an absolute path:

```
import os.path

filename = os.path.expanduser('~/2of12inf.txt')

with open(filename, "rU") as flink:
```

opens a file named `2of12inf.text` in the current user home directory, for example.

Comment: the 2of12inf should be a string, not literal.

Comment: @ITNinja: Yup, was still editing..

Comment: do you mean that I need to def the file

Comment: Out of curiosity, is it better practice to use the `with` syntax if you are simply reading the file into a list? Would `open(fl).read()` be bad?

Comment: @cwallenpoole: It'll still be closed automatically *if you are using cpython* (the reference count drops to 0 immediately, and it'll be closed and cleared quickly). In Jython or IronPython, it can potentially stay open much longer.

Comment: @cwallenpoole: and use `.readlines()` to read it into a list. :-)

Comment: _os.path.expanduser('~/2of12inf.txt')_ looks for the file in use users home directory. Lots of time, opening in the current directory is proper thing for a utility to do. I'd be pretty annoyed if an application like vim only worked on absolute paths or files in my home directory.

Comment: @tdelaney: sure it is, but you'd be surprised how many questions are being asked here on SO about why 'writing to this file doesn't work', and similar, where the OP doesn't know about current working directories.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters - fair enough!

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for the tip re: IronPython and Jython. I rarely use those so I had no way of knowing.

As to `read` vs. `readlines`, that was effectively a typo on my part. You are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use the example below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# open file
f = open ("/etc/passwd","r")

#Read whole file into data
data = f.read()

# Print it
print data

# Close the file
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably enclose the filename in quotes (and add an assignment operator between flink and open):

```
flink = open("2of12inf.txt", "rU")
```

I also strongly advice, as IT Ninja said, to use the with construct to open a file:

```
with open("2of12inf.txt", "rU") as flink:
    # do stuff...
```

This will take care of closing the file as it would do with a try-finally block.

Comment: *This will take care of any exception raised from the open statement* No it will not. It *will* close the `flink` file if an exception is raised in the suite of code under the `with` line, but that is something different.

Comment: Right, corrected. Thanks!